# Capacitor microphones for recording studios

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-current, capacitance, signal-processing

This question is formulated exclusively for high school students precisely to interest them in a more concrete way.

> <del>Condenser microphones are characterized by a capsule that functions exactly like an electronic capacitor. They are generally cylindrical in shape or consist of two conducting plates spaced apart with an insulating material in between, or are of variable capacitance.
> The two plates are polarized to interrupt the current flow. The capacitor can store a small amount of electricity inside it. The capacitor takes a while to accumulate electrical charges in the membranes. When both plates are charged, the flow of alternating current in the capsule is interrupted. When the microphone picks up a vibration in the air it begins to oscillate in a similar manner to the source. Oscillating varies the distance between the plates of the condenser, then as the distance varies also varies the capacitance of the microphone capsule. The variation of the capacity creates an alternating current with a trend similar to that of the capsule. The electric signal thus generated represents faithfully the captured sound.</del>

**1.** We know that a parallel-plate capacitor with flat parallel plates of area $A$ and spacing $d$ has capacitance (with a dielectric):

$$C=\frac{\epsilon A}{d} \tag 1$$

**2.** If $L$ it is the height of the two cylinders with $R>r$, I know that capacitance is given by

$$C=\frac{Q}{\Delta V}=\frac{2\pi L \epsilon}{\ln\left(\dfrac Rr\right)} \tag 2$$

> **If a student asked me this question**: What is the importance of a capacitor for the sound, i.e. how do you turn an acoustic signal into an electrical one (alternating current - $\text{AC}$) to avoid distortions when I am recording, i.e. why the capacitors are used for studio recording microphones?

I think that the paths of my physical thoughts are the circuits:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C @>>> \text{RLC}@>?>>Z\, \color{red}{\text{impedance}}@>?>> \color{red}{\text{acoustic wave}} @>?>> \color{red}{\text{electric signal AC}}\\
\end{CD}

> Using the physical formulas, how can I motivate the student's question or my possible path below?

Comment: I don't understand - what exactly do you want to do? To justify the effect described in the text using that formula? If yes, then can you not just say that, for a fully charged capacitor, $Q$ is constant, so $\Delta V \propto 1/L$, where $L$ (the distance between the capacitor plates) is a function of time?

Comment: @SuperCiocia Very kind moderator I would like to motivate the importance of a cylindrical capacitor for sound, i.e. how do you turn an acoustic signal into an electrical one (alternating current) to avoid distortions when recording. I hope this is clear.

Comment: @SuperCiocia In other words, why are cylindrical capacitors used for studio recording microphones, for example. You are allowed to improve my question by editing it.

Comment: ok I don't know the answer sorry, also I have mistaken $L$ for the distance between the plates whereas it's actually the length of the capacitor (the plates' distance is $R-r$).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the description.  The microphone has a cylindrical capsule but the capacitor is not cylindrical.  The plates are more like thin disks. So the formula does not apply.

Comment: @nasu I have written that they are generally cylindrical in shape or consist of two conducting plates. I have written that (for example) of a cylindrical capacitor. I certainly can't apply the formula I wrote down; this is a cylindrical condenser microphone. On Amazon there are many microphones built with a cylindrical capacitor.

Comment: @Sebastiano This is what a condenser mike looks like inside. You have misunderstood the description in your quote. Also, note that most modern condenser mikes use *electret* material which is not a simple "two-plate capacitor" at all. See https://mxlmics.com/how-condenser-microphones-work/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone

Comment: @Sebastiano Can you provide a link to one of those microphones based on cylindrical capacitors?

Comment: @nasu I have seen this: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.it%2FCylewet-cilindrica-microfono-condensatore-confezione%2Fdp%2FB073XHG49P&psig=AOvVaw0FolCZ4P9_kPwPhL9Sb-5e&ust=1631617175286000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAgQjRxqFwoTCLjN1uvl-_ICFQAAAAAdAAAAABAF and there is written Cylewet CLW1013 - Electret Cylindrical Condenser Microphone, 2-pin, 9 x 7 mm.

Comment: @alephzero I have read differents post and comments of links in the web (for example this https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.it%2FCylewet-cilindrica-microfono-condensatore-confezione%2Fdp%2FB073XHG49P&psig=AOvVaw0FolCZ4P9_kPwPhL9Sb-5e&ust=1631617175286000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAgQjRxqFwoTCLjN1uvl-_ICFQAAAAAdAAAAABAF). However I have improved my question. Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Sebastiano The internal construction is a "cylinder", but it is two flat circular plates radius $R$ separated by a  small distance $h$. Now, a student might ask you "why are the  plates *circular* and not a different shape like a square?" That would be a good question, but the answer is probably too complicated for a high school student. You could ask the student the question "Well, why do you think most *drums* are circular and not square" - and the basic reason is the same :)

Comment: @alephzero I have read with a lot lot lot attention your excellent comment. I have understood your concept :-) but I am curious for my work like a teacher. I not like to do the same lessons: in fact I change often my style and the formulas. Please can you (for example) with the formulas (that I understand better) all the steps for your comment and if is it possible to my question? Is it, now more clear, the question? Thank you very much. I go to bed. Good night.

Comment: @Sebastiano I believe that the title in the Amazon link is misleading, maybe due to misstranslation of the equivalent page on Amazon US or Canada.  I suppose it should be "Microfono cilindrico a condensatore (con eletretto)".  This is supported by the fact that the word "Electret" was not translated and left in the english version. The adjective "cilindrico" should refer to the microphone itself and not to the capacitor.

Comment: @nasu Surely you have right. I am an user that have a low level skills in English language. I hope that all users have understood the reason of my informations. My best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily connect the microphone to the classic problems involving a capacitor connected to a battery and asking what happens if you change the distance between the plates. By changing the distance between the plates you change the capacitance. With fixed voltage this means that the charge on the plates will change (increase or decrease). Changing charge means current (charging or discharging currents. These currents are used to detect the sound producing the vibration of one of the plates of the capacitor. They use electrets so you don't actually need a battery. The charge on the electret produces the voltage across the plates even in the absence of external battery. One of the plates of capacitor is a thin membrane of electret with or without a metal coating. So, in principle the microphone with the electret can function without external bias. But in order to increase the sensitivity they include a transistor in the capsule, to amplify the signal and possibly for impedance matching. So, now you need external power for the transistor and most of these electret micropohones need external bias.

Comment: Thank very much very again for your answer. I think to have understood it. Please can you transform it with the formulas? Thanks. +1

Comment: Sorry, what kind of formula?

Comment: I absolutely don't think I can remember everything you wrote. But is everything you wrote possible to translate with physical formulas that allow me to interpret your answer mathematically? Thank you.