# Electric force between two point positive charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ moving at $v$ velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields

Consider two positive charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ separated by $r$ distance. The are both moving with $v$ velocity (same direction).
Considering the electric field are moving with $c$ velocity, what would be the Electric force on $q_2$ by $q_1$?

Comment: Duplicate : [Charges and relative motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651969/charges-and-relative-motion/652210#652210).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Charges and relative motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651969/charges-and-relative-motion)

Answer (score 0):

The fields due to Point charge, that we get using Lienard-Wiechert potentials:
$$  \text{E} = {q\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r'}| \over [(\vec{r} - \vec{r'})\cdot\vec{u}]^3} \cdot [(c^2-v^2)\vec{u} + (\vec{r}-\vec{r'})\times(\vec{u}\times \vec{a})] $$
$$  B = {1\over c} (\vec{r}-\vec{r'}) \times E $$

Now, for a point charge moving with constant velocity, the value of these fields along the direction of motion are:

$$ E = {q\over 4\pi \epsilon_0}{1-v^2/c^2\over R^2}\hat{R} $$
$$ B = {1\over c^2} (\vec{v}\times \vec{E}) = 0 $$
And now we can calculate the Force using Lorentz law:
$$ F = {q_1 q_2\over 4\pi \epsilon_0}{1-v^2/c^2\over r^2} $$

Comment: Please do not post complete answers to questions that look like homework questions.  This is not a site for doing other people's homework.  This is a site for education, and posting complete answers is the opposite of that.  Please reword the answer to give guidance, not an answer.  Or if you prefer, just delete the answer.

Comment: Well how did you get $B= 0$?. Both charges are moving so there should be a magnetic field. Neither $v$ nor $E$ is zero here.