# Charge travelling with constant speed and Maxwell equations

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

I am reading "Matter and Interaction" by Chabay and Sherwood chapter 23 (4 edition). They state that accelerating charge generates wave satisfying Maxwell equations. They also provide an illustration of it. I am trying to think about charge moving without acceleration (with constant speed). It also generates electric field (wave) and magnetic field (wave), but I am failing to see why they do not satisfy Maxwell equation. Or maybe they do?

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/electric-field-associated-with-moving-charge). **(2)** [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge). **(3)** [Charges and relative motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651969/charges-and-relative-motion/652210#652210).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to think about charge moving without acceleration (with constant speed). It also generates electric field (wave) and magnetic field (wave), but I am failing to see why they do not satisfy Maxwell equation.

The fields produced do satisfy Maxwell’s equations. However, this specific solution to Maxwell’s equations is generally not considered to be a wave. The energy in this field remains near the charge and does not radiate away from it. Also, any changes in the field propagate at the speed of the charge rather than at the speed of electromagnetic waves.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/704470/what-is-physically-happening-during-em-wave-propagation-from-an-oscillating-char/704774#704774