# A question about Coulomb's law for one moving and one stationary charge

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

let one charge is moving and another charge is stationary (compulsory). Then the electric force between them can be calculated by coulomb's law?

Comment: Yes, but there is also a magnetic force.  Or you can consider solely the electrostatic force, but then you have to consider special relativity to get this right.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, do you mean there are electric force and magnetic field to moving charge and there is only electric force to stationary charge?.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Sorry but I can't understand about electrostatic force. As far as i know the electric field isn't static since charge is moving; time-varying.. sorry

Comment: Related : [Charges and relative motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651969/charges-and-relative-motion/652210#652210).

Comment: @Frobenius, Thank you. But what i want is; one is stationary and another is moving

Comment: Sure, @KHJ. I do post the link as related, not as answer or duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. In the frame of the stationary charge $Q$, the electric field is: $$\mathbf E_Q = \frac{kQ\mathbf r}{r^3}$$ The force at a (moving) test charge $q$ is $\mathbf F = q\mathbf E$.

But the inverse is not true. The force from the test charge in $Q$ is not equal and opposite. In the frame of $Q$, the electric field of a moving charge is not simply: $$\mathbf E_q = \frac{kq\mathbf r}{r^3}$$ And there is also a magnetic field due to its movement in relation to $Q$ frame.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer

Comment: *The force from the test charge in Q is not equal and opposite.* Why? Have you calculated it? Do you think that the total momentum of the two charges is changing?

Comment: @Ghoster, Do you agree with this answer? or not?

Comment: @Ghoster the momentum conservation on movement of charges includes emission of EM radiation. Looking only at the charges, the Newton's third law doesn't apply.

Comment: The OP was vague regarding the motion. If the moving charge is in uniform motion, there is no radiation and the forces are equal and opposite. So I think your answer is misleading.